# Can I archive my GitHub repo if it’s also a published npm module?

Tags: git, npm

I have a GitHub repo for an npm module that I no longer maintain.  I’ve deprecated it on npm, but it still has active weekly downloads.  Can I still archive the git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish a package to NPM, it gets downloaded from there. You can archive the git repo if you no longer want to maintain it.